# Getting javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException error after changing mail server from MS outlook to OWA

Tags: java

We changed the mail server from MS-Outlook to OWA exchange server and the below email ID is giving errors.

```
INFO (MobEmail.java:41) [2014-10-03 09:26:12,944] - Intializing the SMTP Protocol Configurations.

INFO (MobEmail.java:47) [2014-10-03 09:26:12,944] - Configured the Host

INFO (MobEmail.java:78) [2014-10-03 09:26:12,945] - Mail Sending Service.....

INFO (MobEmail.java:83) [2014-10-03 09:26:12,945] - from::::finance@mmg.co.gy

INFO (MobEmail.java:91) [2014-10-03 09:26:12,946] - Adding the Receipents finance@mmg.co.gy

INFO (MobEmail.java:98) [2014-10-03 09:26:12,946] - Message Object Prepared

INFO (MobEmail.java:104) [2014-10-03 09:26:14,943] -

INFO (MobEmail.java:105) [2014-10-03 09:26:14,943] - javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

INFO (SMSUtility.java:867) [2014-10-03 09:26:14,944] - Messagekey1073DR
```

Comment: Can you post a part of your code? So we can look whether there is something wrong

Comment: Dear JBeenenga , It was working before just after the change it stops sending mail.

Comment: Have you tried to log the whole exception with Stacktrace? Maybe there are more information about the Exception